# login function using local json file in swift

Tags: json, swift, authentication

I have a login.json file as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "saranya@reachwebexperts.com",
      "pass": "pass"
    },
    {
      "name": "test@gmail.com",
      "pass": "1234"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2@gmail.com",
      "pass": "password"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i have a login screen with username and password, so when the user enters correct username and password matching this json file, the login is successful else not.

I have parsed the json file, but unable to match it with the username and password.

Comment: Show your parsing function and how your are trying to compare it.

Comment: please add code what you tried.

Comment: In your JSON, is it `age` or `pass` or both?

Comment: sorry its pass,entered here by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Parse the *JSON* using **`Codable`** using the below *models*,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let data: [User]
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let pass: String?
    let age: String?
}
```

Let's say user entered the following details while logging in,

```
let username = "saranya@reachwebexperts.com"
let password = "pass"
```

After parsing, you can match the username and password using **`contains(_:)`**.

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let isValid = response.data.contains { $0.name == username && $0.pass == password }
    print(isValid)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```